# My "GetKeyDown" mettod doesn't work unity version 2018.4.34f1

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a platform game with the space bar to jump so i tried to use the GetKeyDown mecanic but it didn't worked i tested these two methods and there was no error message but it didn't worked `if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")){Debug.Log("good");}`  `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){Debug.Log("good");}` thanks

Comment: Can you add some clarification? The rest of your code?

Comment: I have nothing for now exept this

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a loop?

Comment: I put it in the update mettod

Answer (score -1):

try this example with space from the scripting API ;)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It still didn't worked